# USB charger limits: 9 V, 1.7 A but only 5 V, 2 A? Not exactly anti-proportional

Tags: power-supply, usb, charging

The standard USB charger from the box of a smartphone (model EP-TA20EWE) has the following limitations:

- 9 V at 1.67 A = about 15 W.
- 5 V at 2.0 A = 10 W.

Should that charger not be able to reach 3 A at 5 V, which would equal around the same wattage as 9 V, 1.67 A?

Comment: What does that get you if the cable is only rated for 2A?

Comment: @PlasmaHH The cable is rated for 30V, and 9V 1.67A but also 5V 2.4A works fine on a different charger, a 30W Powstro with 3 USB ports. The limitations per port are 3A at 5V to avoid frying one port. I wonder, how a cable which is rated for 9V1.67A can be limited to 5V2A.

Comment: Conductors are rated for current, insulation is rated for voltage. With the right insulation your USB cable could be rated for 1MV/2A but not for 30V/2.1A

Comment: @PlasmaHH You can find USB cables with AWG 22 for power lines these days. AWG 22 can go up to 7A, if you tolerate a 75C conductor temperature. What will really limit the current in these cables is your voltage drop requirements. At 52mOhm/m, there is a 300mV drop @ 3A due only to the power line conductors alone for a 1m cable (1m for VCC, 1m for GND).

Comment: @gstorto what will really limit the current is the usb standard. AFAIK there is no commercial usb charger yet that can sense conductor thickness and material

Comment: This is not a "constant wattage" supply, rather it is one which can charge devices in a legacy nominal 5v mode or alternately charge compatible devices in a special high rate mode which uses a higher voltage thus requiring less current,  limiting the required cable size and losses.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I do not agree, the limitation is OPs power supply design. Maybe you will overheat by a bit the USB connector if you are trying to exceed the nominal 2A. However, the current will damage or be limited by the switching mechanism of the power supply.

Comment: Maybe when using more than 2.0A the efficiency doesn't comply to standards anymore.

Comment: @DanielP Is that a reason to put in a limitation?

Answer (score 2):

Chargers with variable voltage output (PD or QuickCharge) use some switcher-based converters, which involves an inductor and active MOSFET switch. The converter is usually the same for 5V and for 9V, only the set point gets changed in accord with link negotiations.

If the inductor/switch is economically designed to handle 2 A (to provide 9V at 1.67A), it can't deliver more than 2 A when the set point is changed to 5 V output. That's likely why the manufacturer limited the 5V-output to 2 A only. It looks like this design is limited on DC side, and expectations to have "proportional" 15W-output in both modes are unfounded.

Answer (score 1):

*Should that charger not be able to reach 3 A at 5 V, which would equal around the same wattage as 9 V, 1.67 A?*

**If** the total power delivered to the output is the limit of the design then yes, you're right. It **could** (not should) be designed for 15 W at 5 V or 9 V.

**But** at 5 V a current of 3 A would be needed. As few devices actually support charging at 3 A at 5 V, 2 A might be enough. That means some cheaper components can be used. Often for example a diode which supports up to 3 A is more expensive than a diode which can support up to 2 A.

Also, the phone with which the adapter comes supports 15 W charging at 9 V already so there is **no need** for 3 A at 5 V for that combination.

So the 10 W charging at 5 V appears to be a deliberate choice to save some cost and also, supporting 15 W at 5 V would not bring any benefit to the package (phone + charger).

Comment: The main reason is a usb standard. The things you mentioned may have influenced that standard though

Comment: Another consideration that you may want to add to your answer is the contact current rating of the USB connector at the end of the cable and/or its mate in the phone. This is most likely a micro-B type connector. The contact rating may very well be the limiting issue. Here is one example rated at 1A per contact: https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Hirose-Connector/ZX62D-B-5PA830?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvYKGyZxp8jxgWbApVXx0RFRAN%2fG9EvgO8%3d . Here is another example rated for 1.8A: https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/JAE-Electronics/DX4R005JJ6R1500?qs=sGAEpiMZZMuTlc58v6LkthFrTyZ9wE3%252b8Jo7pvppShk%3d

Comment: If you search you can find Micro-B type USB connectors with higher current rating. I have seen them at 3A from Wurth Electronics at prices 2 to 3x the lower current rated types.

Comment: Some large powerbanks sometimes actually are able to draw up to 5V 4A (Anker 21000mAh).